# 504 Gateway Timeout even when Timeout is set to 600

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, timeout, php7

I have the follow unresolved problem regarding PHP and Apache. I have a long running script that ALWAYS return 504 Gateway Timeout after 30 seconds running. However, if I check in `/server-process`, I can see that the request is still going on. Before being suggested, I'm not expecting it to be a cron job as this long process should finish just under a minute and for current situation, I needed it to run inside browser. Here's what I've set the server:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
- Timeout 600

/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
- max_execution_time = 300
- max_input_time = 300
```

Here's my server info:

```
root@izzystorage-core:~# lsb_release -r
Release:        16.04

root@izzystorage-core:~# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-09-18T15:09:02

root@izzystorage-core:~# php -v
PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Do you guys have any Idea what's going on with my server?

**edit**

1. I don't have `mod_proxy`
2. This is only one server without load balancer in between

Answer (score 1):

I have a Mysql query running in a PHP script that scans a lot of data and responds in 2 minutes.
I was always getting 504 gateway timeout after 30 sec.
After trying all usual advice, I ended up understanding that the issue was lying on the Open Shift route that I use to access the PHP script.
The Open Shift default route Time out is 30 seconds.
I changed the route annotation to 5 min and it did the trick !
See here for details:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812807/openshift-service-proxy-timeout

Answer (score 0):

After several hours adjusting `Timeout`, `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` parameters and multiple `service apache2 restart` without result, I put back the original parameters (600, 300, 300) and restart the whole server with `shutdown -r now`. Upon server back online, all problem suddenly resolved.